# Polygon Map in WordPress/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

This [code](https://codepen.io/jhawes/pen/ujdgK) is working fine in WordPress/PHP but when I get the `coords` dynamic it stopped working.

I have made an `alert` of the JavaScript variable, which gives the data as i have inserted it in WordPress custom field.

may be there is a parsing error..

I get the data like this.

```
var coords = $("#map").attr("data-coordinates");

// Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
var triangleCoords = [
  coords
];
```

Is there any one can help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Which data stored in data-coordinates?

Probably you should remap coords

```
   // <div id="map" data-coordinates="33.5362475, -111.9267386, 33.5104882, -111.9627875, 33.5004686, -111.9027061">
   var triangleCoords = [];
   var items = coords.split(',');
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 2) {
       triangleCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(items[i], items[i + 1]))
   }
```

Comment: The following data is stored :     

    {lng: -113.47113103222, lat: 53.531600034458},
    {lng: -113.46934897258, lat: 53.530568304362},
    {lng: -113.46835550221, lat: 53.529993448717},
    {lng: -113.46689425672, lat: 53.529374507025},